# How to add ng-class inside directive template in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to do something like this:

```
template:  "<div ng-if=\"successData\" ng-class=\"{ 'bounceInDown': successData == true,bounceInDown: successData == false}\" style=\"border-radius: 2px;padding: 7px;margin-right: 10px;\" class=\"pull-right alert-success\">test</div>"
```

But `ng-class` is not working.
Anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: We need to see your directive code. You have probably lost successData from scope

Comment: I also think it is the problem here is my scope: `scope: {
            isSuccess: '=',
            messageSuccess: '@messageSuccess',
            messageError: '@messageError'
        }` I have here: `ng-if=\"successData\" access to that scope`

Comment: You need to show where `successdata` is defined

Answer (score 0):

ng-if is enough simply set the $scope.successData= true or false in controller, it will work. following code with small change

template:  "test"

if you need further help, share me your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The directive template will only be shown if successData is true, therefore the ng-class is unnecessary. You can move the `bounceInDown` class to the class attribute of the div element as shown below.

```
template: '<div ng-if="successData" style="border-radius:2px;padding: 7px;margin-right:10px;" class="bounceInDown pull-right alert-success">test</div>'
```